# Search and replace, special pattern for indent (ex: newline = '\r')

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, indentation

I am cleaning up some minified css. I found [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_a_newline_after_given_patterns) helpful for adding a newline before/after a search match. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/indent-multipe-lines-quickly-in-vi) has a pretty exhaustive list of ways to indent with VIM, but it DOES NOT include a command-line pattern that will indent, like `\r` for ading a newline.
 The answers in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732618/auto-indent-in-vim-string-replacement-new-line) rely on surrounding formatting with the `]p` pattern or using macros, neither of which serve my purposes.

Here's my command to add a new line before and two new lines after all matches for `}`:
`:/[}]` 
 
then 
 `:%s//\r&\r\r/g`
I do something similar for `{`. However, for all matches to `;` I need to add a `\r` (newline) and indent a determined number of spaces. I don't want to rely on vim's auto indent settings. I want to indent a number of times that i set manually in the command string.

Comment: Could you give a before/after example for clarity?

Comment: What do you mean? Where the links to the relevant threads not enough? Giving a detailed explanation of my incomplete command would be tangental to my question. If you want to understand `:search` and `\r` go to the thread i linked to.

Comment: This one: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_a_newline_after_given_patterns

Comment: I updated my answer based on my guess at the before/after @Tumbler41 asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways of doing this sort of thing are:

### With a `:substitute` command

```
:%s/\(foo\)/\r    \1/g
```

This will add a newline and four spaces of "indent" before every matched `foo`

The `\(` and `\)` around the search expression `/foo/` capture the match into a group, and then the `\1` uses the captured group in the replacement. This obviously isn't necessary for simple values of `/foo/`.

### With a `:global` command

You can also do this with the `:normal` and `:global` commands. For example the following command will indent all lines that match the regexp `/foo/` and add a line above them:

```
:g/foo/normal >>O
```

This works similar to a `:substitute` command, but instead of making a substitution, it applies the normal mode operations indent (`>>`) followed by add a line above (`O`) to each matching line.

You can adjust the normal mode commands to perform different operations as necessary.

For more details:

```
:help :global
:help :normal
```

### Using `:s` and `:g` to Unminify CSS

I'm a little unclear on *precisely* what you're trying to achieve, but if the goal is to e.g. turn this:

```
margin:0;padding:0;font-family:verdana;
```

into this:

```
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:verdana;

^^^^ <- one level of indent
```

I'd do so with the following two commands:

```
:%s/;/;\r/g
:g/;/normal >>
```

If, for some reason, you need to add a specific number of spaces that doesn't match your shiftwidth settings, you could instead do:

```
:%s/;/;\r/g
:g/;/normal i    
             ^^^^ <- type four spaces after the `i`
```

### Macros

In practice, for the specific case mentioned above, I'd probably have used a recursive macro:

- `qqq`: Clear out the `q` register. Necessary for recursive macros,
- `qq`: Start recording in the `q` register,
- `/;[^$]<cr>`: Find the first semi-colon not followed by a newline,
- `:left<cr>`: Remove any existing indentation (to remove automatic indentation),
- `>>`: Add one level of indent,
- `na<cr><esc>`: Jump back to the semi-colon,
- `@q`: Recurse,
- `q`: Finish recording,
- `@q`: Run the macro.

You could also record a macro that runs on a single line and then apply it to every line with the global command.

```
qqqqq:left<cr>>>f;a<cr><esc>@qq@q
:g/;/norm @q
```

The macro versions *look* complicated written down, but because they just use normal editing commands recording them comes naturally (with a bit of practice) and using them is a lot faster than it looks.

Comment: Your first solution works, but the second only runs the search as global. Is there a key I'm supposed to press to get it to run the insertion?

Comment: One more thing:` \1` adds an indent, right? Wait.. no.... where is the indent command?? That is the answer I'm looking for. It is replacing, not indenting. So I cannot add `x` number of indents per match with this command. Please re-read the question.

Comment: 'I want to indent a number of times that i set manually in the command string."

Comment: @AndÚ The spaces *before* the `\1` are the indent. However many spaces/tabs you type will be the indent added.

Comment: @AndÚ In the second solution, there is no insertion. The global command runs the normal mode indent command `>>` and add line command `O`. If you need more indent, you can adjust the commands given, as stated.